# How to add custom CSS to ui-dialog-content? 

Tags: css, jquery-ui

```
<div id="dialog" title="dialog" style="display:none" > 
    Test
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

I want all the text in "p" tag to be bold

Comment: Consider reading a tutorial on basic CSS it will help you in the long run, [MDN CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css)

Answer (score 3):

css :

```
#dialog p {font-weight:bold}
```

jquery

```
 $('#id').find('p').css("font-weight","bold");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#dialog p{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

in your stylesheet would do the trick.

Comment: but he has set `display: none;` to his parent div. How is he going to see the result?